# Why can't we compare a node with 'None' to check for 'cycle' in singly linked list?

Tags: python, linked-list

"When I compare the .nextnode with None to check whether the node is linked to something or not....it gives an AttribueError....why?"

Please see the two different codes below....Only the while Conditions are different the rest of the code is same.

In the first case I compare .nextnode with None and I get an error...... but in the second case I don't get any error and my code runs successfully.....why?

```py
class Node():

    def __init__(self,value):

        self.value = value
        self.nextnode = None
```

Case 1:

```
def cycle_check(node):
    fast,slow=node,node
    while fast.nextnode!=None or fast.nextnode!=slow:
        if fast.nextnode==slow:
            return True
        else:
            fast=fast.nextnode
    return False
```

Case 2:

```
def cycle_check(node):
    fast,slow=node,node
    while fast and fast.nextnode:
        if fast.nextnode==slow:
            return True
        else:
            fast=fast.nextnode
    return False
```

Test Code:

```
# CREATE CYCLE LIST
a = Node(1)
b = Node(2)
c = Node(3)

a.nextnode = b
b.nextnode = c
c.nextnode = a # Cycle Here!


# CREATE NON CYCLE LIST
x = Node(1)
y = Node(2)
z = Node(3)

x.nextnode = y
y.nextnode = z


#############
class TestCycleCheck(object):

    def test(self,sol):
        assert_equal(sol(a),True)
        assert_equal(sol(x),False)

        print ("ALL TEST CASES PASSED")

# Run Tests

t = TestCycleCheck()
t.test(cycle_check)
```

The error message in first case is:

"AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'nextnode'"

Comment: How are you calling these functions? Looks like you've passed `None` to them

Answer (score 1):

At some point in the execution of case 1, `fast` becomes `None`. Executing `None.nextnode` will throw an `AttributeError`, as you have found. In case 2 this is prevented in the condition of the while loop by `while fast`, which is equivalent to `while fast is not None`.

Answer (score 0):

since there are two condition `OR` in case 1, it will allow fast.nextnode to be None when `fast.nextnode!=slow` is true, in this case, while accessing nextnode you are getting error.

Comment: This is not addressing the correct problem. `fast.nextnode` being `None` doesn't cause the error. The error is caused when `fast` is `None` because you are trying to get `None.nextnode`.

Comment: when fast.nextnode is none, it will allow fast to be none which will cause the problem